# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [...] did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, predicate, criteria-api

I'm using Criteria API to build named queries using filters. It works on normal String comparisons but when filtering on UUID it throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [67279329-5096-4196-9E73-748B33122CE2] did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [67279329-5096-4196-9E73-748B33122CE2] did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]
```

There are several questions addressing this issue but none of them worked, I tried the following:

- adding `@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)` to the entity field
- adding `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")` to the entity field
- adding `@Type(type="uuid-char")` to the entity field

**Foo entity:**

```java
@Entity
//lombok stuff
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    //...
}
```

SQL Variant:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id                    UUID    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name                  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

**FooController:**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/foo")
public ResponseEntity<List<Foo>> findFoos(@RequestParam Map<String, String> filterArguments) {
    FooFilter filter = filterMapper.map(filterArguments);
    FooSpecification spec = new FooSpecification(filter);

    List<Foo> foos = fooRepo.findAll(spec);
    //...
}
```

**FooSpecification:**

```java
public class FooSpecification extends SpecificationHelper implements Specification<Foo> {
    private final FooFilter filter;

    public FooSpecification(FooFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Foo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        Predicate predicate = null;

        predicate = createIdPredicate(root, filter, criteriaBuilder, predicate);
        predicate = createNamePredicate(root, filter, criteriaBuilder, predicate);
        // ...

        return predicate;
    }

    private Predicate createIdPredicate(Root<Foo> foo, FooFilter filter, CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate predicate) {
        Predicate returnPredicate = predicate;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filter.getId()))
            returnPredicate = addAndPredicate(cb, predicate, cb.like(cb.upper(foo.get("id")), "%" + filter.getId().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        return returnPredicate;
    }

    private Predicate createNamePredicate(Root<Foo> foo, FooFilter filter, CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate predicate) {
        Predicate returnPredicate = predicate;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filter.getName()))
            returnPredicate = addAndPredicate(cb, predicate, cb.like(cb.upper(foo.get("name")), "%" + filter.getName().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        return returnPredicate;
    }
}
```

`addAndPredicate` is a simple helper method that just uses criteriaBuilder.and(predicate,newPredicate)

`FooFilter` only has String fields

Comment: Looks like createIdPredicate creates predicate for id as a String rather than UUID.
Try to parse string from FooFilter into UUID: UUID.fromString(filter.getId())

Comment: @tentacle I don't quite understand your comment, CriteriaBuilder's `like()` method only accepts string based `Expression`s. Only way your solution would word is by adding `"" + UUID.fromString(filter.getId())` which yields the same result as before. I also updated the question, the uuid should also be compared with '%' wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue using typecasting provided by the Criteria API.

**Before:**

```java
addAndPredicate(..., ..., cb.like(cb.upper(foo.get("id")), ...));
```

**After:**

```java
addAndPredicate(..., ..., cb.like(cb.upper(foo.get("id").as(String.class)), ...));
```

From: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as(java.lang.Class)

> `<X> Expression<X> as(java.lang.Class<X> type)`
>
> Perform a typecast upon the expression, returning a new expression
>   object. This method does not cause type conversion: the runtime type
>   is not changed. Warning: may result in a runtime failure.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `FooFilter` contains only `String` fields, and you are trying to compare `String id` with a `UUID` object in `createIdPredicate()`. And that's why the exception is thrown. There are 2 solutions:

- Either, you should replace `filter.getId().toUpperCase()` part in `createIdPredicate()` with `UUID.fromString(filter.getId())` as suggested by @tentacle
- Or, change your `FooFilter` filter so that the `id` would be of type `java.util.UUID`.

By the way, IMHO, comparing `UUIDs` with `like` is not a good idea, because one `UUID` can never be like another `UUID`, each `UUID` object is unique. Your predicate should check the equality of ids transferred by `FooFilter` and the one from `DB`.

Comment: - First solution will not work as explained in my original comment.


- Second could work but what I'm trying to achieve is a simple String comparison, all my params coming from the controller are Strings, sure I could (and probably should) map the strings to an actual object, same thing for dates etc.


I follow your opinion 100%, but sadly as a programmer I have to follow business requirements, and if bussines persists in filtering on id's _I just do what I gotta do_

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar trouble and @edward answer actually helped me a lot :)

One thing that I have changed is the use of `cb.equal` instead of the `cb.like`, because when searching for a specific id the `equal` way seems to be more efficient.

One other thing I've done is to parse only once my filter param with `UUID.fromString(uuid_string_param)` so that I just parse the param once and dont have to cast database UUID field to string in order to get the match.

Cheers.